# I can't run any npm command in cmd return os.tmpDir()

Tags: node.js

```
PS C:\Users\Gowthamreddy\Desktop\serverjs> npm install express
C:\Users\Gowthamreddy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\osenv\osenv.js:49
  return os.tmpDir()
            ^

TypeError: os.tmpDir is not a function
    at C:\Users\Gowthamreddy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\osenv\osenv.js:49:13
    at Object.exports.<computed> [as tmpdir] (C:\Users\Gowthamreddy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\osenv\osenv.js:14:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gowthamreddy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\config\defaults.js:89:18)        
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gowthamreddy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:4:18)
```

I am unable to run npm command. How can I slove this?

Comment: Node.js version?

Comment: node.js version 16.17.0